# Installing GTK2 in windows !

Tags: perl, gtk

I am trying to install GTK in windows and use GLADE develop GUI interface. For GTK i need to install Glib, which is creating a problem for me.  I am trying to do:

```
perl Makefile.pl
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

but I am getting stuck on the `dmake` step.  The error I am seeing is:

```
---------------  dmake.exe:  Error code 1, while making 'Glib.o'-------------
```

Is it possible to use GLADE and Glib with perl on windows? If so, am I making a mistake in building it?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5399368/edit) and provide additional information: the complete output until the failing step, and which distribution of Perl you are using.

Comment: The quickest way to get up and running with Perl+Gtk on Windows is probably the 'Camelbox' Perl distribution.  It's a little dated but the mailing list is a good place to tap into Perl+Gtk+windows talent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using gtk 2.22 in xp and 7 compiled in xp with msvisual c++ 2010 and activePerl 5.012. It was a dirty job but it works for me. I did this a few months ago and these are the notes I had written.

1. get msvcr100.dll and put it in system32 folder.
2. compile ExtUtils-Depends and ExtUtils-PkgConfig
3. get Glib and comment the line with unistd.h in gtk\include\font??foo (it's a linux header!)
   add include stdlib.h ,  io.h and getopt.h in the same file. Get it from http://www.pwilson.net/sample.html
4. compile Cairo
5. compile Pango (I had some problems but since I did not pretend to use pango I just comment 3 references to gtk2perl????.xs)
6. compile gtk (the dirty job again: comment references to gdkcairo.xs and gdkprintcontext)

I just use a few of cairo so it works for me.
PDF creation (for exemple) will fail! If you need all the features may be you need to cross compile all this stuff in linux.